# Query to find closest number and return the associated discount in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Here is the exact situation:

```
Monthly_Budget | Extra_Bonus
---------------------------
300,000,000    |   0.40
420,000,000    |   0.60
580,000,000    |   0.90
1,000,000,000  |   1.20
1,600,000,000  |   1.45
2,900,000,000  |   1.55
4,160,000,000  |   1.65
6,600,000,000  |   1.80
10,000,000,000 |   2.10
14,160,000,000 |   2.25
20,000,000,000 |   2.60
26,000,000,000 |   3.00
33,000,000,000 |   3.40
50,000,000,000 |   4.00
73,000,000,000 |   4.50
```

The first Column shows the budget and second one indicates the relevant bonus.
The rule says for example if the budget is **300,000,000** or **350,000,000** or **410,000,000** (anything less than next record) the bonus will be **0.40** (the previous Record).
my question is how i can query this exact given example?

```
    SELECT  Extra Bonus
    FROM    Monthly_Budget_TBL
    WHERE   Monthly_Budget .....?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 declare @actualBudget integer = 350000000
-- --------------------------------
 Select Extra_Bonus from table
 Where Monthly_Budget =
    (Select Max(Monthly_Budget) from table
     Where Monthly_Budget <= @actualBudget)
```

Comment: it worked, somehow it has automatically changed into this:
        SELECT        Extra_Bonus
        FROM            Monthly_Budget_Table
        WHERE        (MonthlyBudget =
                             (SELECT        MAX(MonthlyBudget) AS Expr1
                                FROM            Monthly_Budget_Table AS Monthly_Budget_Table_1
                                WHERE        (MonthlyBudget < @actualBudget)))

but! it doesn't return the 300,000,000 and 420,000,000 and . . . but all the values in between are working fine.
i am coding in VB  and using datasets and tableadaptors

Comment: Any idea what did i do wrong, appreciate your help.
thank you

Comment: sorry i didnt pay attention, the problem was the " < " which should be changed to " <= ". thanks

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your discovery

Answer (score 0):

So you have some budget as input and want to get the closest bonus that has a budget lower or equal your input?

in that case this should work:

```
SELECT Extra_Bonus, {exampleBudgetVariable} - Monthly_Budget as diff FROM Monthly_Budget_TBL
WHERE {exampleBudgetVariable} - Monthly_Budget >= 0
ORDER BY diff ASC
LIMIT 1
```

{exampleBudgetVariable} should be replaced with your example budget in whatever language you are coding

Comment: thanks
I went your way:
        SELECT        Extra_Bonus, @Monthly_Budget - Monthly_Budget AS diff
        FROM            Monthly_Budget_TBL
        WHERE        (diff >= 0)
        ORDER BY diff
it gives me the "invalid column name 'diff'" Error

Comment: Forgot that you can not use aliases in the WHERE clause, i have edited my post

Answer (score -1):

In order to demonstrate this properly, I'm going to make up a couple additional tables. Let's pretend you have a `Employees` table with an `EmployeeID` column and a `Name` column, and `MonthlySalesSummary` table with an `EmployeeID` column and `SalesAmount` column. It's this `SalesAmount` value that you want to match up against the budget for each salesperson. Here's what the query might look like:

```
SELECT e.Name, b.Extra_Bonus
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN MonthlySalesSummary s ON s.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Extra_Bonus FROM Monthly_Budget_TBL WHERE Monthly_Budget > SalesAmount ORDER BY Monthly_Budget
) b
```